# how can switch's custom right textview be center aligned?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

This is my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/form_widget_switch_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/form_widget_switch"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="text" />

    <com.example.daffodil.formvalidation.widgets.typefaced.SwitchButtonTF
        android:id="@+id/form_widget_switch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:switchMinWidth="40dp"
        android:textOff=""
        android:textOn=""
        android:thumbTextPadding="5dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the output I'm getting:

[image]

**Problem :** I want text to be center vertically aligned but as you can see its top edge is aligned with top edge of the switch.

**Edit:** based on comments

**Why am I using TextView :** I want text view to move dynamically left or right side of the switch.so I use both TextView and Switch and changing their params dynamically to move text left or right.

I want output similar to setting Switch's button text attribute.

SwitchButtonTF class which presently I'm using:

```
/**
 * Switch with typeface attribute added.
 */
public class SwitchButtonTF extends Switch {

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public SwitchButtonTF(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context, null);
    }

    /**
     * Initialise view.
     *
     * @param context context
     * @param attrs   layout attributes
     */
    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            Fonts.getInstance(context).applyTypeFace(this, context, attrs);
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public SwitchButtonTF(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public SwitchButtonTF(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context, attrs);
    }
}
```

Any help?

Comment: Reply if you this solution don't work.

Comment: android:layout_width="match_parent" for TextView

Comment: why do you need to use TextView? your SwitchButton has text property

Comment: I want text view to move dynamically left or right side of the switch.

Comment: so I use both TextView and Switch and changing their params dynamically to move text left or right.

Comment: in fact your code is correct and it must give you whatever you are looking for, I'm confused why you are getting this result, may be it's something in your SwitchButtonTF, try to use a regular `Switch` and see if the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` in your textview as it is inside the relativelayout.Also set the height of the textview to `wrap_content`.
So your textview xml should be

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/form_widget_switch_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/form_widget_switch"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any problem using `LinearLayout` in place of `RelativeLayout` then can you try this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">    
        <com.example.daffodil.formvalidation.widgets.typefaced.SwitchButtonTF
            android:id="@+id/form_widget_switch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:switchMinWidth="40dp"
            android:textOff=""
            android:textOn=""
            android:thumbTextPadding="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/form_widget_switch_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:text="text" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Edit - try this with `RelativeLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/form_widget_switch_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/form_widget_switch"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="text" />

    <com.example.daffodil.formvalidation.widgets.typefaced.SwitchButtonTF
        android:id="@+id/form_widget_switch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:switchMinWidth="40dp"
        android:textOff=""
        android:textOn=""
        android:thumbTextPadding="5dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It would be great if you tell problem with the relative layout or my code.

Comment: SwitchButtonTF is simple switch button with type face added.

Comment: I'm not getting output what I want. I tried many cases but getting the same output shown in the image

Comment: @SandeepSharma can you share the source code of `SwitchButtonTF`. I think there is some problem

Comment: what `Fonts.getInstance(context).applyTypeFace(this, context, attrs);` this line does

Comment: for applying different font to Switch view

Comment: @SandeepSharma I checked your xml and it's working fine at my end. I have again edited my answer check if that helps

Comment: which device are you testing?

Comment: @SandeepSharma Moto g

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/form_widget_switch_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/form_widget_switch"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="text" />

    <com.example.daffodil.formvalidation.widgets.typefaced.SwitchButtonTF
        android:id="@+id/form_widget_switch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:switchMinWidth="40dp"
        android:textOff=""
        android:textOn=""
        android:thumbTextPadding="5dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```